# Ubuntu 20.04 Ethernet and WiFi not working

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

Apologies if this has already been asked. I've been using Ubuntu pretty flawlessly for about a week or so now and all of a sudden I cant connect to the internet via WiFi or Ethernet, when i did lshw -C network I got *-network UNCLAIMED for the Ethernet connection at least. Whats strange is that when I boot into an older version of Ubuntu or my Windows dual boot everything is working fine, and like I said this had done for the past week. I don't especially care about the wireless connection any tips or solutions?